# run-time error '5' maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix

Tags: runtime-error

Yesterday, I ran the following script in excel and it worked, but now it throws an error:

`(run-time error '5' )`

in the line:

`Distance = Mid(Distance, InStr(1, Distance, ">") + 1, InStr(1, Distance, " ") - InStr(1, Distance, ">") - 1)`

```css
Sub Поиск_ближайшего_СБС()

Set Points = Worksheets("Точки")
Set SBS = Worksheets("СБС")

Dim Cordinate11, Cordinate12, Cordinate21, Cordinate22 As String

i = 2
Do While SBS.Cells(i, 1) <> Empty
    Rows_of_SBS = i
    i = i + 1
Loop

i = 2 
Do While Cells(i, 1) <> Empty
    
    Dist = 1000
    Cordinate21 = Points.Cells(i + 1, 3) 
    Cordinate22 = Points.Cells(i + 1, 4) 
    
    For j = 2 To Rows_of_SBS 
        Cordinate11 = SBS.Cells(j, 2) 
        Cordinate12 = SBS.Cells(j, 3) 
        
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = False  
        With IE
            .Navigate "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" _
            & Cordinate11 & ",+" & Cordinate12 _
            & "&destinations=" _
            & Cordinate21 & ",+" & Cordinate22 _
            & "&mode=driving&language=ru&sensor=false"
            Do While .Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            For Each MyTable In .Document.getElementsByTagName("text")
                Distance = MyTable.innertext
            Next
            Distance = Mid(Distance, InStr(1, Distance, ">") + 1, InStr(1, Distance, " ") - InStr(1, Distance, ">") - 1)
                        If CDbl(Distance) < Dist Then
                Dist = CDbl(Distance)                  s = j       
            End If
        End With
        IE.Quit
        Set EI = Nothing
        
    Next j
    
    Points.Cells(i + 1, 5) = Dist  
    Points.Cells(i + 1, 6) = SBS.Cells(s, 1)   
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

```
            '
```

Comment: +key, but not butter

Comment: .Navigate "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" _
            & Cordinate11 & ",+" & Cordinate12 _
            & "&destinations=" _
            & Cordinate21 & ",+" & Cordinate22 _
            & "&mode=driving&language=ru&sensor=false" _
            & "&Key = AIzaSyDj2Cv2XXjWYi5jkAAHyzCcd6WIc7vY2_s"

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it Excel VBA? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.